# JS regex: one correct match out of three and one false match

Tags: javascript, regex

This JS regex error is killing me - one correct match out of three and one false match.

*If it makes a difference I am writing my script in Google Apps Script.*

I have a string (xml formatted) I want to match three date nodes as follows:

```
<dateCreated>1619155581543</dateCreated>
<dispatchDate>1619478000000</dispatchDate>
<deliveryDate>1619564400000</deliveryDate>
```

I don't care about the tags so much - I just need enough to reliably replace them.  I am using this regular expression:

```
var regex = new RegExp('[dD]ate(.{1,})?>[0-9]{13,}</');
```

These are the matches:

1. `dateCreated>1619155581543</`
2. `Created`

Obviously I understand number 1 - I wanted that.  But I do not understand how 2 was matched.  Also why were `dispatchDate` and `deliveryDate` not matched?  All three targets are matched if I use the above regex in BBEdit and on https://ihateregex.io/playground and neither of those match "Created".

I've also tried this regular expression without success:

```
var regex = new RegExp('[dD]ate.{0,}>[0-9]{13,}</');
```

If you can't answer why my regex fails but you can offer a working solution I'd still be happy with that.

Comment: You get partial matches starting at `date` until `</` You could match the strings like this `<([^<>]*[dD]ate[^<>]*)>\d{13}<\/\1>` https://regex101.com/r/nfdtq0/1 but if you can use an xml parser, than might be better and less error prone.

Comment: Thanks for this.  Your regex is similarly working on iHateRegex but not in my script -weird.  I'm writing this in Google Apps Script so I wonder if there is some bug behind the scenes?  Since GAS has built in XMLservice I will see if I can easily do what I need by parsing the xml.

Comment: You can use it like `var regex = new RegExp('<([^<>]*[dD]ate[^<>]*)>\\d{13}<\\/\\1>');` or `var regex = /<([^<>]*[dD]ate[^<>]*)>\d{13}<\/\1>/;`

Answer (score 1):

The first pattern that you tried `[dD]ate(.{1,})?>[0-9]{13,}</` matches:

- `[dD]ate` Match *date* or *Date*
- `(.{1,})?` Optional capture group, match 1+ times any char (This group will capture *Created*)
- `>` Match literally
- `[0-9]{13,}` Match 13 or more digits 0-9
- `</` Match literally

What you will get are partial matches from `date` till `</` and the first capture group will contain *Created*

The second pattern is almost the same, except for `{0,}` which matches 0 or more times, and there is no capture group.

Still this will give you partial matches.

---

What you could do to match the whole element is either harvest the power of an XML parser (which would be the recommended way) or use a pattern what assumes only digits between the tags and no `<` `>` chars between the opening an closing.

Note that this is a [brittle solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags).

```
<([^<>]*[dD]ate[^<>]*)>\d{13}<\/\1>
```

- `<` Match literally
- `(` Capture **group 1** (This group is used for the backreference `\1` at the end of the pattern

  - `[^\s<>]*` Match 0+ times any character except `<` or `>`
  - `[dD]ate[^<>]*` Match either `date` or `Date` followed 0+ times any char except `<` or `>`
- `)` Close group 1
- `>` Match literally
- `\d{13}` Match 13 digits (or `\d{13,}` for 13 or more
- `<\/\1>` Match `</` then a backreference to the exact text that is captured in group 1 (to match the name of the closing tag) and then match `>`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/MO0oY6/1)

A bit more restricted pattern could be allowing only word characters `\w` around matching `date`

```
<(\w*[dD]ate\w*)>\d{13}<\/\1>
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TRT6Ll/1)

```js
const regex = /<([^<>]*[dD]ate[^<>]*)>\d{13}<\/\1>/;
[
  "<dateCreated>1619155581543</dateCreated>",
  "<dispatchDate>1619478000000</dispatchDate>",
  "<deliveryDate>1619564400000</deliveryDate>",
  "<thirteendigits>1619564400000</thirteendigits>",
].forEach(str => {
  const match = str.match(regex);
  console.log(match ? `Match --> ${str}` : `No match --> ${str}`)
});
```